# PHP's date_diff() is behaving unexpectedly

Tags: php

It's probably just me being dumb, but ...

```
<?php
   $startDate = date_create('2019-11-01');
   $endDate = date_create('2019-12-01');
       
    $interval = date_diff($startDate, $endDate);
    
   var_dump($interval);       
?>
```

in [PHPfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/) gives (as expected):

> object(DateInterval)#3 (15)
> { ["y"]=> int(0)
> ["m"]=> int(1)   <===   this is what gives me problems on my local machine
> ["d"]=> int(0)
> ["h"]=> int(0)
> ["i"]=> int(0)
> ["s"]=> int(0)
> ["weekday"]=> int(0)
> ["weekday_behavior"]=> int(0)
> ["first_last_day_of"]=> int(0)
> ["invert"]=> int(0)
> ["days"]=> int(30)
> ["special_type"]=> int(0)
> ["special_amount"]=> int(0)
> ["have_weekday_relative"]=> int(0)
> ["have_special_relative"]=> int(0) }

Check out the value of `m`, which is number of months.

However, on my local machine, ***the same code*** gives:

```
class DateInterval#4 (16) {
  public $y =>
  int(0)
  public $m =>
  int(0)                          <======  why ??!!
  public $d =>
  int(30)
  public $h =>
  int(0)
  public $i =>
  int(0)
  public $s =>
  int(0)
  public $f =>
  double(0)
  public $weekday =>
  int(0)
  public $weekday_behavior =>
  int(0)
  public $first_last_day_of =>
  int(0)
  public $invert =>
  int(0)
  public $days =>
  int(30)
  public $special_type =>
  int(0)
  public $special_amount =>
  int(0)
  public $have_weekday_relative =>
  int(0)
  public $have_special_relative =>
  int(0)
}
```

OK, I will concede that is is 30 days, but the answer that I was looking for was 1 month, and `$interval->m` is zer0.

What am I missing?  I don't know what version of PHP the [PHPfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/) web site uses, but I am using 7.3.11 locally.

Comment: PHPFiddle runs 5.6.40

Comment: I'd say you found a bug in the newer PHP. A difference between dates with two different month values should return an interval with a nonzero months field...

Comment: FWIW, denoting any time delta in "months" is broken by definition, since there's no single defined value for the length of a month… :) Not *your* fault, mostly PHP's fault…

Comment: Now, that's not true. A calendar month is not a constant length, but it used all over the place in everyday life. The difference between the same date in consecutive months is a difference of a month, whether that's 28, 29, 30, or 31 days. Being able to compute deltas in terms of these broken-out values returned by `date_diff` is mostly useful precisely _because_ calendar months (and years) don't translate into a fixed number of days; if all months were the same length, you could just get the delta in days and divide.

Comment: @Mark But talking about time deltas in terms of months introduces a ton of edge cases with undefined behaviour. The delta between March 30th and April 30th is… 1 month? OK, let's add that delta of 1 month to January 30th. What result do you expect? ‍♂️

Comment: @deceze: I study calendars as a hobby; you're not telling me anything I don't know. :) I'm just saying, that in everyday life we have contracts and rent and credit card billing intervals and things that are specified in terms of months. The edge cases are going to be edge cases, but the utility is still there.

Comment: Sound like this php bug: [Bug #79452](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=79452)

Comment: @Mark Sure, and in everyday life we can fudge based on common sense, and/or those edge cases are explicitly explained ("payment due on last of the month", "on every 15th, except if it falls on a holiday or weekend, then next business day", "let's meet again in a month, like… the 28th?"). Computers don't do that intrinsically and need custom coding for every edge case, so PHP having a completely unsafe `DateInterval` built in which in many cases you can't use safely and need to code around anyway isn't helpful IMO.

Comment: It's helpful enough to be a common function built into spreadsheets (e.g. Excel DATEDIF), many varieties of SQL, most programming language date libraries... it's not really fair to criticize PHP specifically for following common practice, especially when there are so many other valid criticisms of PHP. :)

Comment: @Mark To point to a *sane* version of this: [Python's `timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) only expresses deltas up to weeks and refuses to do anything with larger units than that. That's pretty safe to use and layer your own logic on top based on business rules.

Comment: yup, Python's native timedelta doesn't do months, which is why the internet has a bunch of variations on this; https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-get-the-number-of-months-between-two-dates-in-python

Comment: @Mark Yup, it requires you to define your own logic for what a "month" is and you can use `timedelta` as a building block in that algorithm. PHP *doesn't* let you define your own logic unless you avoid `DateInterval` entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the difference is in the timezone.

try this:

```
<?php
   date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

   $startDate = date_create('2019-11-01');
   $endDate = date_create('2019-12-01');
       
   $interval = date_diff($startDate, $endDate);
    
   var_dump($interval);  
/*
object(DateInterval)#3 (16) {
  ["y"]=>
  int(0)
  ["m"]=>
  int(1)
  ...
*/
```

also try this:

```
<?php
   $startDate = date_create('2019-11-01 23:00');
   $endDate = date_create('2019-12-01 23:00');
       
   $interval = date_diff($startDate, $endDate);
    
   var_dump($interval);       
   /* outputs the same ["m"]=> int(1) as above */
```

Probably date_diff looking for a difference between UTC timestamp and you have the default timezone on your PHP set to some positive value.

Let's say you have some default timezone which is UTC+02:00 therefore
`date_create('2019-11-01')`
actually makes a date *2019-10-31 22:00:00 (UTC)*
and `date_create('2019-12-01')` actually makes a date *2019-11-30 22:00:00 (UTC)*

now you can see they have no whole month difference.

But you can catch another funny effect:

```
<?php
   //assuming your timezone is UTC+something
   $startDate = date_create('2019-10-31'); // creates a date 2019-10-30 XX:00 UTC
   $endDate = date_create('2019-12-01');   // creates a date 2019-11-30 XX:00 UTC
       
   $interval = date_diff($startDate, $endDate);
    
   var_dump($interval);       

/*
object(DateInterval)#3 (16) {
  ["y"]=>
  int(0)  
  ["m"]=>
  int(1)   sic(!)
  ["d"]=>
  int(0)   sic(!)
*/
```

Also you may have unexpected result if your timezone has the daylight saving.

```
<?php
   // Germany has the daylight saving shift at last Sunday of March and October.
   date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin'); 

   $startDate = date_create('2020-03-28 03:00');
   $endDate = date_create('2020-03-29 02:00');

   $interval = date_diff($startDate, $endDate);
    
   var_dump($interval);  //   ["d"]=>  int(1)  ["h"]=>  int(0)

   
   
   $startDate = date_create('2020-03-28 03:00');
   $endDate = date_create('2020-03-29 03:00');

   $interval = date_diff($startDate, $endDate); 

   var_dump($interval); //   ["d"]=>  int(1)  ["h"]=>  int(0)


   $startDate = date_create('2020-03-28 03:00');
   $endDate = date_create('2020-03-28 03:00'); // the same
   $endDate->modify('+23 hour');

   $interval = date_diff($startDate, $endDate);
    
   var_dump($interval);  //   ["d"]=>  int(1)  ["h"]=>  int(0)
```

*PHPFiddle* has the default timezone set to UTC, therefore it gives one month difference by default.

To avoid that, just perform all date calculations in UTC from the beginning:

```
<?php
   $timeZone = new DateTimeZone('UTC');

   $startDate = new DateTime('2019-10-31', $timeZone);
   $endDate = new DateTime('2019-12-01', $timeZone);
       
   $interval = date_diff($startDate, $endDate);
    
   var_dump($interval);
```

Comment: I laughed at (what I thought of as) your naivety when I read "probably the timezone", because they both have the same timezone. And then my jaw dropped, because adding ` `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');` did actually result in a difference of one month. I don't claim to understand this, but thank you for the answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a bug and is related to your server time zone. You can use this workaround:

```
   $startDate = date_create('2019-11-01 UTC');
   $endDate = date_create('2019-12-01 UTC');
       
   $interval = date_diff($startDate, $endDate);
    
   echo $interval->m; //1
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have hit a bug in PHP 7.3.11 that wasn't there in the older version used by PhpFiddle. It's also fixed the latest stable version, 7.4.11, so you should just upgrade your local PHP.

(I notice that 7.3.11 is what ships with MacOS; if you're on a Mac, you can install a newer PHP with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh).)

Comment: I updated (XAMPP) to 7.4.11 and still get the same result.

Comment: Weird, must be our different time zones. I got the same behavior as you in 7.3.11, but got the expected 1-month delta in 7.4.11. But it sounds like you got your answer anyway, so great!

Comment: Nope, the time zones are identical. I can `var_dump()` if you want. Both at TZ 3 (Berlin) - which is what mystifies me - doubly so when UTC works (upvote)

Comment: No, I wasn't questioning that your time zones are identical. I was just guessing that the reason you're still seeing the bug in 7.4.11 and I'm not is maybe because _you_ and _I_ are in different time zones.  But isn't Berlin UTC+2 (soon to be UTC+1)? What does "TZ 3" mean?

Comment: When I evaluate, I get `$startDate = date : 2019-11-01 00:00:00.000000, timezone : Europe/Berlin, timezone_type : 3`, so I guess that I was wrong there : timezone_***type*** (whatever 3 means). Anyhoo, thanks for the answer